# Using Theme.DeviceDefault with AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, illegalstateexception

I have an application that is implemented with `AppCompatActivity` and a theme based on `Theme.AppCompat`. I would like to create a flavor of the same application, but that uses the `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme. When I change the theme, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I considered replacing all instances of `AppCompatActivity` with `FragmentActivity`, but this causes a lot of features to break.

Is there a way to use the `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme in an application that uses `AppCompatActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of, but you might want to consider the following;

As new versions of the platform are released new components are introduced for example per the source code it seems Theme.AppCompat will properly handle styling on different components/resources that previously were not available and set important things such as the view inflater class  `<item name="viewInflaterClass">android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater</item>`

This is why it uses the V7 base theme as its parent:

```
 <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat">
```

Your other option, that I did not tested, is to drill down into what resources is in the theme you want using and copy them all, this of course is painful.

> ```
> <!-- The default theme for apps that target API level XX and higher.
>      <p>The DeviceDefault themes are aliases for a specific device’s native look and feel. The
>      DeviceDefault theme family and widget style family offer ways for you to target your app
>      to a device’s native theme with all device customizations intact.</p>
>      <p>For example, when you set your app's {@code targetSdkVersion} to XX or higher, this
>      theme is applied to your application by default. As such, your app might appear with the
>      {@link #Theme_Material Material} styles on one device, but with a different set of styles on
>      another device. This is great if you want your app to fit with the device's native look and
>      feel. If, however, you prefer to keep your UI style the same across all devices, you should
>      apply a specific theme such as {@link #Theme_Material Material} or one of your own design.
>      For more information, read <a
>      href="http://android-developers.blogspot.com/20XX/XX/material-everywhere.html">Material
>      Everywhere</a>.</p>
>      <p>Styles used by the DeviceDefault theme are named using the convention
>      Type.DeviceDefault.Etc (for example, {@code Widget.DeviceDefault.Button} and
>      {@code TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.PopupMenu.Large}).</p>
>       -->
> ```